# How to include in a style a new section?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to define a "title" style in word 2013 which include a new page and new section.

Actually, I want to set my title in a new page and centered on this page.

I can change the style of the title in order to do a new section but I don't know how to include a new page before.

Briefly: I just want to isolate in the middle of a new page.

EDITED:

I created another style for a paragraph after this title with a page break. This forces me to add an introduction paragraph after every title but it is ok.

The solution of Michael Franck makes this:

[image: Click to see the image]

It doesn't make a page with only the title but create a frame.
I'm surprised that this is not easy as I thought. It's pretty common to write a title on an empty page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want a style that creates a title page like this:

[image: Title Page Example]

You can do this quite "easily" actually.

First, create a new style:

[image: Create new Style]

Name it anything you want, and then press Modify:

[image: Name and Modify]

Base it on any style you want, I chose `Title` and `Normal`. Also, set any font and formatting options you want here:

[image: Style Based on...]

Next, click on `Format` and choose `Frame...`, this is where we will center the Title on the page:

[image: Frame Options]

[image: Centered!]

Now click `Format` again and choose `Paragraph`. On the `Line and Page Breaks` tab, check the `Page break before` box:

[image: Page Break Before]

And that's it!

It's not perfect, as it doesn't really work if it's the first page and may need some tweaking. Have a play, it should be enough.

Comment: Thank you but it doesnt work. I edited my question.